# Create and Bind Gridview at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have WINFORM and I want to setup and bind the dataSource of my DataGridView at runtime.

I have following code for the same, but its not seem to work

```
DataTable dtAppointmentForPrint = new DataTable();
GetAppointments(null, out dtAppointmentForPrint);

DataGridView temp = new DataGridView();
temp.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
temp.DataSource = dtAppointmentForPrint;
temp.Refresh();
```

When I explore the datasource of the gridview it's there, but column count is zero.

Comment: You need to add the `DataGridView` to some parent. Do you add it? In other words it needs to be displayed in screen.

Comment: I actually don't want to show  it on the form, just need to pass to some other function to print it. That function accepts datagridview as parameter and prints its content.